# How to update the edited information to the list without using database in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app using ionic and angularjs. I have car brands and their related car models listed in the first UI view.The scenario is, the user will select a car brand from list, so on selection it will be redirected to the next page , where the user can edit both the car brand and their car models. And update it to the list. The problem I face here is in the updating the information to the list. I tried using services and many other possible way but couldn't succeed in updation. Any sample code or plnkr is most welcome because its breaking my head and Im struck here for the past two-weeks. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the `<select multiple="true">` tags and then using `ng-repeat`, `ng-options`, and/or  `ng-change` in this app? If not and it sounds relevant to your situation I will be glad to help you through this.

Comment: I tried all the possibilties you mentioned and also my colleague gave ideas  to decalre function inside a factory or services but it didn't work and also a felt very complicated to handle. @AustinHunter

Comment: How are you declaring this car brand list? Can you show us some code so we can help you out!

Comment: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SmbVhUnNCH4qbcrcpXNR) I have attached plunker of how my first page looks like. From there Im unable to move forward. @AustinHunter

Comment: I hope someone will help me with this..

Comment: I am looking over your code. Is this copy and pasted from your current code? Or did you retype it all into plnker

Answer (score 0):

So I have looked over your code and the way you have things setup is very confusing. I have tried my best to help you out with what little information we have. I have made a new plnkr. Take a look at it and give it a try. The plnker you shared had lots of mistakes in it. Let me know if anything I did helped out. If not, please clarify what exactly is not working, etc... More information on everything. But if this helps, Cool.

https://plnkr.co/edit/sYppXuE0Q10RNBTTkWiH?p=info`plnkr`

Comment: I guess your trying to help me with the delete function in the plnkr . But I want help in editing of the information.